# Ansible Playbook stuck in Task Part

Tags: ansible

I have written a simple play for installing pip and expect on my clients using ansible. However, the execution is stuck in the TASK part.

My code-

```
---
- hosts: mygroup
  tasks: 
  - name: Install packages
    yum: name= {{ item }} state=installed
    with_items: 
     - pip
     - expect
```

Debug- [only the Task part where the execution is stuck]

```
TASK [Install packages] ********************************************************
task path: /home/netman/lab7/prsh1271_play.yaml:4
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/packaging/os/yum.py
<192.168.1.2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/packaging/os/yum.py
<172.16.1.2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<192.168.1.2> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/netman/.ansible/cp/61004433e3 192.168.1.2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.16.1.2> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/netman/.ansible/cp/3e78e2ce1a 172.16.1.2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Please help resolve.

Answer (score 1):

you could add a "become: true", so it runs as the root user.

so you have:

```
---
- hosts: mygroup
  become: true
  tasks: 
  - name: Install packages
    yum: name= {{ item }} state=installed
    with_items: 
     - pip
     - expect
```

Answer (score 0):

Package installation requires root user or root like user. Can you add the user in the sudoers file and try again if not added

Also re run the playbook using -vvvv for verbose logging and entry the verbose logs - which would be helpful for debugging.

Comment: The snippet is the output of -vvv command. However, I could resolve the issue. My machine did not have access to the internet, on resolving that I was able to execute the task.

Answer (score 0):

The playbook might be stuck because the command you run in the stuck task issues an input prompt, which you don't see when you run the playbook.

Since no input is ever supplied to the prompt, it just sits there and waits forever.

The solution (if this is indeed the problem):
Change your tasks such that you provide any necessary inputs directly in your Ansible tasks, thus avoiding input prompts.